# How I update the Google USB Driver on a Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, android, adb

I am trying to update my Google USB Driver to perform [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) debugging with my Google devices with a laptop running Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I currently have Google USB Driver v7:

[image]

I went to https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb to download the latest driver, which is v13, however when trying to update my drivers, Microsoft Windows says that my driver is already up to date,  as the screenshots below show. Why? Is v7 the most recent driver available for Win7?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am going to say with near certainty that the newer driver is incompatible with Windows 7

Comment: As far as I remember the correct way for forcing a new driver is `Let me pick from a list`... and then the button `have disk`.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the driver has an update, I would recommend the software [Driver Booster](https://www.iobit.com/de/driver-booster.php) from IObit. This is a very reliable software (personal experiences) and works well. If it doesn't find any drivers to be updated, it is extremely certain that there isn't a more recent driver for Windows 7.

Anyway, I would also recommend you update your computer to a more recent Windows version, such as Windows 10.